# Логирование работы батника

Tags: java, windows, cmd, javac

Захотел сделать компиляцию Java-файла через батник, потом понял, что ошибок видно не будет, решил попробовать создавать логи с помощью того же батника, но ничего не выходит. Пытался поставить перезаписывание файла через '>', однако, результат такой же.

Код самого .bat:

```
echo  Date: %date%, time: %time% >> "C:\app\logs\log.txt"
cd "C:\app\xyz\some\Main"
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\javac.exe" Main.java >> "C:\app\logs\log.txt"
echo ===================================== >> "C:\app\logs\log.txt"
```

Comment: лучше освоить системы сборки - это значительно облегчит многие вещи (и логирование тоже)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, не спорю, но подумал, что лучше будет начать с чего-то сложного

Comment: зачем начинать со сложного? начинать надо с простого.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, не так выразился. Хочу это тоже изучить, другими словами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, если `javac` есть в переменных среды, то можно не указывать полный путь (за исключением, когда у вас их много и вы хотите использовать какой-то конкретный).

Во-вторых, обычно выключают вывод команд на экран, указывая в начале `*.bat` файла `@echo off`.

В-третьих, логирование удобно сделать таким образом, объединяя сразу несколько команд, чтобы не писать у каждой строчки:

```
@echo off
>output.txt 2>&1(
  command1
  command2
  ...
  commandN
)
```

В-четвертых, если вы хотите добавлять в файл используйте `>>` вместо `>`, последний переписывает файл с начала.

Используйте `2>&1`, для переадресации **stderr** в **stdout**, чтобы выводить и ошибки тоже.

Comment: Спасибо, в особенности за третье. Всё работает, ошибки выводятся. Но не могу понять структуры выражения >output.txt 2>&1()

Comment: @Андрей про 2>&1 в конце ответа написано =) >output.txt - это перенаправляет stdout в файл output.txt